# Modification format date in phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have a column CMD_DATE in PhpMyAdmin (Varchar 16),

I want to have something like this :

23/09/2013 (so without the time)

How can i do it in PhpmyAdmin ?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Since it's varchar(16) just select the 1st 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

I just wonder why do store date as a string. In my opinion, it is a better idea to revisit the design of your database and store a date as a date, if you can.

You can for example use foreach loop to read the old date value and insert the newly formatted value into a new field in each record and the best way to convert that string would be probably this:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($string));
```

Or you can skip that and just use mysql's STR_TO_DATE() function.

```
UPDATE the_table
   SET new_column = STR_TO_DATE(old_column, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

If you can't change the db, then when displaying you can remove the last 5 characters like this:

```
echo substr($string, 0, -5);
```

Then you will get this string: '23/09/2013'